# HTML/CSS Add dropdown to right of sidemenu

Tags: html, css

I have tried to add drop-down options to my current fixed sidebar menu.

When I try adding new lists to add the extra menus, it just displays them below. When I hover over `Three`, I want `Three One` to be displayed to the right of `Three` and `Three Two` below `Three One`.

When I hover over `Four`, I want `Four One`" to be displayed to the right of `Four` and `Four Two` below `Four One`. With the same happening when I hover over `Four One One`

Below is my HTMl and CSS

```css
body {
    font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
}

header {
    background: #424242;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-right: #FA5858 3px solid;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 175px;
}

header ul {
    padding: 0;
}

header a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
    ;
    display: block;
}

span {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

header ul li {
    padding: 15px;
}

header ul li:hover {
    background-color: #FA5858;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Menu</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
 <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
   <center>
    <h1>Logo Here</h1>
   </center>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href=""><span class="far fa-newspaper"></span>One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href=""><span class="far fa-list-alt"></span>Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three</a>
    </li>
    <ul>
     <li>
     <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three One</a>
     </li>
     <li>
     <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three Two</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <li>
     <a href=""><span class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></span>Four</a>
    </li>
    <ul>
     <li>
     <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Four One</a>
     </li>
     <ul>
      <li>
      <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Four One One</a>
      </li>
      <li>
      <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Four One Two</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     <li>
     <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Four Two</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <li>
     <a href=""><span class="far fa-question-circle"></span>Five</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and you have smile on your face :)

html

```
<header>
 <div class="container">
<center>
  <h1>Logo Here</h1>
</center>
<ul>
  <li> <a href=""><span class="far fa-newspaper"></span>One</a> </li>
  <li> <a href=""><span class="far fa-list-alt"></span>Two</a> </li>
  <li> <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three</a> 
    <ul>
    <li> <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three One</a> 
        <ul>
            <li> <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three One One</a> </li>
            <li> <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three One Two</a> </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
    <li> <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three Two</a> </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
 </header>
```

and improve css

```
body {
font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: #2E2E2E;
}

header {
background: #424242;
color: #ffffff;
border-right: #FA5858 3px solid;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 175px;
}
```

header ul {padding: 0;}

```
header a {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
    }

    header li {
display: block;
position:relative;
 }

span {
margin-right: 15px;
  }

    header ul li {
padding: 15px;
     }

  header ul li:hover {
background-color: #FA5858;
 }
  header ul li ul{display:none;}
    header ul li:hover ul{display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:170px; background:#fff; width:200px;}
      header ul li ul li a{color:#000; display:inline-block; width:100%;}
     header ul li ul li{display:inline-block; width:100%; padding:0;}
    header ul li ul li ul{display:none !important;}
  header ul li ul li:hover ul{display:block !important;}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fd9hedd/)

Comment: Thanks so much :D I accepted the answer. I tried to upvote to but i dont have enough rep yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
<header>
<div class="container">
<center>
  <h1>Logo Here</h1>
</center>
<ul>
  <li> <a href=""><span class="far fa-newspaper"></span>One</a> </li>
  <li> <a href=""><span class="far fa-list-alt"></span>Two</a> </li>
  <li> <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three</a> 
    <ul>
    <li> <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three One</a> </li>
    <li> <a href=""><span class="fas fa-user-secret"></span>Three Two</a> </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and

```
body {
font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: #2E2E2E;
```

}

```
header {
  background: #424242;
color: #ffffff;
border-right: #FA5858 3px solid;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 175px;
}

header ul {
padding: 0;
}

header a {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
display: block;
position:relative;
}

span {margin-right: 15px;}

header ul li {padding: 15px;}

header ul li:hover {background-color: #FA5858;}
header ul li ul{display:none;}
header ul li:hover ul{display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:170px; background:#fff; width:200px;}
header ul li ul li a{color:#000; display:inline-block; width:100%;}
header ul li ul li{display:inline-block; width:100%; padding:0;}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7p9tpjL/)

Comment: Thanks.. One small problem though. When i hover over three, its opens both sub menu's.. it shouldn't open the third until i hover on the second. here https://jsfiddle.net/L07xh8bu/

Comment: Now if you are satisfy then please small click on right check and give me green :)